# Jquery UI Datepicker highlight days not working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I done some customization in the script for hightlight days. Its working fine with Chrome browser, but not in Firefox. There is a class "hightlight" added for specific dates in arrays (see screen shot), but the class is not generating on Firefox.. Any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance !

[image]

```js
var dates =['05-20-2017','05-21-2017','05-22-2017','05-23-2017','05-24-2017','05-25-2017','06-01-2017','06-02-2017','06-03-2017','06-04-2017','06-05-2017','06-06-2017','06-07-2017','06-08-2017','06-09-2017','06-10-2017'];

$('#datepicker44').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    //defaultDate: new Date('03/10/2017'), // this line is for testing
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});
$('#datepicker44').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
});
function highlightDays(date) {
 for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
 if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
 return [true, 'highlight'];
 }
 }
 return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
td.highlight > a {
 background: #E50104!important;
 color: #fff!important;
}
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker44">
</p>
```

Comment: please share fiddle

Comment: Just run my snippet please..

Comment: Highlight class is not adding on mozilla

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan Yes.. actually that is the problem..

Comment: use toDateString() instead of toString()

Comment: Date can be tricky and hard to work with. Some operations on Date objects cannot be chained. That's why everyone uses [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). The syntax is simple, chain-able and has anything you could possibly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/8yxmxnr7/2/

I have changed this conditon:

```
if (new Date(dateSplit[0] + " " + dateSplit[1] + ", " + dateSplit[2]).toString() == date.toString()) {
```

Also split the date

```
var dateSplit = dates[i].split("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly comparing two strings instead of comparing two dates. By default, Javascript outputs this when you use .toString() on it:

```
Tue May 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

I have no idea why it works in Chrome, but the point is you can't rely on `date.toString()` to be consistent cross-browser.

Instead you have to create two separate date objects and compare their `.valueOf()`, which would be a JavaScript timestamp integer.

```
if (Date.parse(dates[i]).valueOf() == date.valueOf()) {
   // do your thing...
}
```

For the above to work you'd need to pass in strings `Date` can understand, like `YYYY-MM-DD`. I'm not entirely familiar with all the strings formats a `Date` object parses correctly and how it relates to user's `locale`.

I personally use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It has a much better API, clean docs and I find it quite easy to use and understand. On large projects I no longer wait until I need `moment.js` anymore. I just add it from the start. It is rare that I need to remove it at the final purge, for not being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you had used a console.log you would have noticed firefox logging "Invalid Date".

Some date formats are not well defined and browsers may behave different.
Rework you code to use a strict format like iso: `2017-05-20`

The same goes for comparing the resulting strings. The output may be different per browser, so compare the individual day/month/year values. You may get away with using `toDateString()` or `toLocaleDateString()`.